# Nvim with prose: how to set up proper `autoformat` line-wrapping

Tags: vim, word-wrap, neovim, autoformat

I'm working a Neovim config for writing prose. I want it to `autoformat` the current paragraph, continuously line-wrapping. Suppose I use `:set formatoptions=a` to accomplish this. This leads to the following annoying behavior, where █ represents the cursor:

```
here is some text
█
```

Now, if I enter insert mode and type `and here is more`, it puts it on the previous line:

```
here is some text and here is more
```

Instead, I want it to leave the newline like this:

```
here is some text
and here is more
```

Looking at `:help fo-table`, I see an interesting option:

```
w       Trailing white space indicates a paragraph continues in the next line.                                                 
        A line that ends in a non-white character ends a paragraph.
```

If I enable it with `:set fo+=w`, now the above example works as desired. However, now if I try manually formatting a long line with `gq`, it will add (actual) trailing spaces to the end of every line:

```
Here is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long line.
```

becomes

```
Here is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very_
very long line.
```

where `_` represents a space.

I want it to *not add spaces* when manually formatting (as when the `w` option isn't used), but I also want it *leave the newline* intact when inserting a second line (as when `w` is used). How can I achieve both of these?

Comment: See `:hel 'formatexpr'`.

Comment: While I'm still curious how to do this, I did remembered that Markdown renderers will remove single newlines when rendering, so it's actually fine to not use `w` and simply let it move the cursor to the end of the preceding line when inserting. This "annoyance" just reflects how it will look when rendered, which is important.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just keep using `gq`, and have the following `autocmd` to get rid of the trailing spaces
`au BufWritePre * :let pos=winsaveview()| silent! %s/\([^[:space:]]\)\s\+$/\1/e | call histdel('search', -1) | call winrestview(pos)`